# Problem while fetching xml through some rss feed

Tags: objective-c, xml, rss, parsing

I was fetching xml through some rss feed.
I am unable to sort items in depth like i have sorted easily "channel -> description" as

```
NSString *resultValue=[[responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"rss.channel.description"] textContent];
```

Above Result: YouTube RSS Feed

My question is how i can parse .... item -> description... i.e (Music video by Andrews \U00a9 1982 MJJ Productions Inc.)
i am getting `nil` if i fetch like `valueForKeyPath:@"rss.channel.item.description"]`

```
Key: rss Value: {
    "_text" = "\n";
    channel =     {
        "_text" = "\n";
        description =         {
            "_text" = "YouTube RSS Feed";
        };
        item =         (
                        {
                "_text" = "\n\t";
                description =                 {
                    "_text" = "Music video by Andrews \U00a9 1982 MJJ Productions Inc.";
                };
                enclosure =                 {
                    length = 294;
                    type = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
                    url = "http://youtube.com/v/Zi_XLOBDo_Y.swf";
                };
                link =                 {
                    "_text" = "http://youtube.com/?v=Zi_XLOBDo_Y";
                };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption that the text you posted is the output from NSLog, the item key in channel points to an array.  `item` is the whole array and any keys applied to item apply to the array itself, not any of the objects in it.  I'm guessing that the runtime is choking on that.